# Can I use an md-hue for the text colour of a toast action button with Angular Material

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to set the colour of the text for toast messages action button, but the only options I can see are md-primary, md-accent and md-warn. When I put `md-primary md-hue-3` as the highlightClass, and then look in the chrome developer tools, I can see that the md-hue-3 colour is being recognised but overridden by md-accent and md-primary.

```
$mdToast.show(
$mdToast.simple()
    .textContent(errorText)
        .action(buttonText)
        .highlightAction(true)
        .highlightClass('md-primary md-hue-3')// Accent is used by default, this just demonstrates the usage
        .hideDelay(3000)
```

[I've attached what I see in the chrome dev tools, with the colour being overridden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbRM.png)